# I know "of" no other area in ... Why "of"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I have met the following sentence and been confused why *of* is necessary after *know*:

> I know *of* no other area in business where the alchemy of power and
> motivation come together in so concentrated a fasion.

I'd like to get answers for the following questions:

- I believe the meaning of the sentence does not change without this *of*. Am I correct?
- If so, why did the author add this *of*?
- What is the speech-of-tagging of this *of*? I guess it's a preposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone asked me "Do you know Joe Biden?" (or any famous person) I could say "No, but I know *of* him." That is, I'm not personally acquainted with him, but I know who he is.

In your example sentence the distinction isn't so clear, but *I know of* means *I'm aware of the existence of.*

Yes, *of* is a preposition.

Comment: +1 And to complete the circle, in your example sentence, it means, "*I am not aware of the existence of any other area in business where...*".